# lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: No declaration for attribute

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I am trying to use dblp data set to convert the xml file to csv file. Right now, I am using iterparse() to parse the xml file.

Here is my code:

```
def iterpar():
    f = open(dblp.xml', 'rb')

    context = etree.iterparse(f, dtd_validation=True, events=("start", "end"))
    context = iter(context)
    event, root = next(context)
    for event, ele in context:
        print event
        print ele
```

However, when I tried to print out something to see what it is, an error was reported:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dblp\Data\XML2csv", line 34, in <module>
    iterpar()
  File "C:\dblp\Data\XML2csv", line 29, in iterpar
    for event, ele in context:
  File "iterparse.pxi", line 208, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:131498)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: No declaration for attribute mdate of element article, line 4, column 19
```

I guess this might result from a fail dtd validation because all attributes are declared in the dtd file. I also tried to google if there are any explanations for my problem but didn't find a good one.

Can anybody explain it and tell me how to fix it? Thank you very much.

-----------update---------

I think I do need the dtd_validation. Otherwise it will report:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'ouml' not defined, line 47, column 25
```

Entities like 'ouml', 'uuml' occurs in xml file, and is defined in the dtd file. Although setting the dtd_validation to be false prevents the No declaration error, but this one will occur.

Comment: Do you actually need to do the dtd validation? If not, then why setting `dtd_validation=True`?

Comment: @har07  
I forget to say, I think I do need the dtd_validation, because the dtd file defines some entities in the xml file. Without dtd file, it will report following error: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'ouml' not defined, line 47, column 25

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your XML or DTD, it's hard to say. It sounds like your XML is violating the DTD because it defines an 'mdate' attribute not listed in the DTD for a specific element. You definitely need the DTD because it defines at least one special character in your XML, so removing the DTD is out of the question.

Is it possible for you to add the 'mdate' attribute into the DTD so that the parser will accept your XML?

```
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name attribute-type #IMPLIED>
```

Comment: This is part of the dtd file for element 'article' : <!ELEMENT article       (%field;)*>
<!ATTLIST article
                        key CDATA #REQUIRED
                        mdate CDATA #IMPLIED
                        publtype CDATA #IMPLIED
                        reviewid CDATA #IMPLIED
                        rating CDATA #IMPLIED
>            I think the mdate is already defined in the dtd file. That's why I feel confused with the problem. Idk how could this happen.

Comment: Agreed. Can you add the XML & DTD to the question?

Comment: Still not working. I get the dataset here, the dtd file is included, and I tried to split the xml file. I am not sure if you would like to have a look. But even if I put the dtd file in the xml, it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file needs to have something similar to this:

`<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">`

If you start fixing `Entity 'ouml'`, you can break the previous dependency.